# connecting google cloud function to cloud sql (postgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect google cloud function with google cloud sql (postgreSQL).

I found document and do exactly same things with document (I think...) but I got error.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/quickstart-connect-functions

my cloud function requirements.txt

```
SQLAlchemy==1.3.12
pg8000==1.13.2
```

and my main.py

```
import sqlalchemy

# Set the following variables depending on your specific
# connection name and root password from the earlier steps:
connection_name = "tram-2020:us-central1:tram"
db_password = "[my password]"
db_name = "guestbook"

db_user = "postgres"
driver_name = 'postgres+pg8000'
query_string = dict({"unix_sock": "/cloudsql/{}/.s.PGSQL.5432".format(connection_name)})

def insert(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    stmt = sqlalchemy.text('INSERT INTO entries (guestName, content) values ("third guest", "Also this one");')
    db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
      sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
          drivername=driver_name,
          username=db_user,
          password=db_password,
          database=db_name,
          query=query_string,
      ),
      pool_size=5,
      max_overflow=2,
      pool_timeout=30,
      pool_recycle=1800
    )
    try:
        with db.connect() as conn:
            conn.execute(stmt)
    except Exception as e:
        return 'Error: {}'.format(str(e))
    return 'ok'
```

And I got error like this

```
Error: (pg8000.core.ProgrammingError) {'S': 'ERROR', 'V': 'ERROR', 'C': '42703', 'M': 'column "third guest" does not exist', 'P': '50', 'F': 'parse_relation.c', 'L': '3359', 'R': 'errorMissingColumn'}
[SQL: INSERT INTO entries (guestName, content) values ("third guest", "Also this one");]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Why error said MissingColumn, did I use wrong query?
Please help me.. How can I solve this problem..

Answer (score 0):

I followed the tutorial and faced the same issue.

I had to change the line of code:

`stmt = sqlalchemy.text('INSERT INTO entries (guestName, content) values ("third guest", "Also this one");')`

to

`stmt = sqlalchemy.text("INSERT INTO entries (guestName, content) values ('third guest', 'Also this one');")`

[image]

Everything worked as expected after that.